# Add event listener to <router-link> component using "v-on:" directive - VueJS

Tags: vuejs2, vue.js, vue-router

I'm attempting to add a custom handler `InlineButtonClickHandler` to a `<router-link>` component's `click` event, so that I can emit a custom `appSidebarInlineButtonClick` event.

But, my code isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

```
<template>
   <router-link :to="to" @click="InlineButtonClickHandler">
     {{ name }}
   </router-link>
</template>

<script type="text/babel">
export default {
  props: {
    to: { type: Object, required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true }
  },
  methods: {
    InlineButtonClickHandler(event) {
      this.$emit('appSidebarInlineButtonClick');
    }
  }
} 
</script>
```

Comment: <a @click="$router.push(to).then(InlineButtonClickHandler)">{{name}}</a> for `vue 3`

Answer (score 155, accepted):

You need to add the [`.native` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components):

```
<router-link
    :to="to"
    @click.native="InlineButtonClickHandler"
>
    {{name}}
</router-link>
```

This will listen to the native click event of the root element of the `router-link` component.

Comment: v-on:click.native is deprecated now, from what I read

Comment: Given that "@click.native" is deprecated in Vue.js 3, an alternate option is to use a button styled as a link and in its @click method call this.$router.push({ path: 'to' });

Comment: ```@click.native``` or ```v-on:click.native``` is now deprecated in new versions of VueJS (>=3), use ```@click.prevent``` instead.

Comment: For Vue3: Until/unless there's an official way handled by VueRouter, this may be an alternative solution: https://github.com/vuejs/router/issues/846#issuecomment-808150258

Answer (score 11):

```
<router-link:to="to">
    <span @click="InlineButtonClickHandler">{{name}}</span>
</router-link>
```

Maybe you can try this.

Comment: This will not be accessible since keyboard users could never activate that `@click` event

Comment: this will create inconsistencies. If, for some reason, you need a padding/margin in between the router link and span you will have zones of the link where  you get routed but the click event is not triggered.

Answer (score 4):

With vue 3 and vue router 4 the `@event` and `tag` prop are removed according to [this](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#removal-of-event-and-tag-props-in-router-link) and instead of that you could use `v-slot`:

```js
const Home = {
  template: '<div>Home</div>'
}
const About = {
  template: '<div>About</div>'
}
let routes = [{
  path: '/',
  component: Home
}, {
  path: '/about',
  component: About
}, ]

const router = VueRouter.createRouter({
  history: VueRouter.createWebHashHistory(),
  routes,
})


const app = Vue.createApp({
  methods: {
    test() {
      console.log("test")
    }
  }
})

app.use(router)

app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@4"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>Hello App!</h1>
  <p>

    <router-link to="/" v-slot="{navigate}">
      <span @click="test" role="link">Go to Home</span>
    </router-link>
    <br/>
    <router-link to="/about">Go to About</router-link>
  </p>

  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing is creating a wrapper component for the router link which emits the native click event as a regular click and then use that component instead:

```
<template>
  <router-link v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners" @click.native="onClick">
    <slot />
  </router-link>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'RouterLinkWithClickEvent',
  methods: {
    onClick(...args) {
      this.$emit('click', ...args);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```