# Can I extend router-link?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

With Vue.JS, is it possible to extend router-link, or bind an event to it, such that for a particular type of link another action occurs?

What I would like to do is specify some links in my application to pop tabs, whilst others do not; e.g.

```
<router-link>no tab</router-link>
<router-link-tab>router view is updated and a tab is pushed</router-link-tab>
```

I would like to avoid binding an event to beforeRoute and inspecting for route urls, but appreciate that this might be the only way forward.

This needs to work across the Vue app, like router-link does, and will not be contained within only one component.

Am I going at this backwards? Would there be pitfalls in defining a custom component that triggered a new tab and called `router.push`, like this? Using RouterLink only to highlight active etc?

```
Vue.component('router-link-tab', {
  template: `<router-link :to="to" @click.prevent="click">
               <slot></slot>
             </router-link>
  `,
  props: {
    to: [String, Object],
  },
  methods:{
    click: function () {
        console.log(this.to);
        this.$router.push(to);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add event listener to <router-link> component using "v-on:" directive - VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091805/add-event-listener-to-router-link-component-using-v-on-directive-vuejs)

Comment: Similar, but I don’t think it’s the same. Where would the inline event handler be defined? My router-links are not all in the same component.

Comment: @stdob-- the second reason that this isn't a duplicate, is that the previous question looks at a single or few uses of adding an event listener. I'd like this to be global; to be defined once for all uses.

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom component:

```
Vue.component('router-link-tab', {
  template: `<router-link :to="to" event="" @click.native.prevent="click">
               <slot></slot>
             </router-link>
  `,
  props: {
    to: String,
  },
  methods:{
    click: function () {
        console.log(this.to)
    }
  }
});
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/6dn8f1nw/ ]

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in the Sandbox for me (at least not in Safari). The click event is only heard by the router-link-tab component and not the router-link; so /tab is never visited (although the click console log does fire).