# Emit event from router-link

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I want to emit an event (to close a modal on the parent component) when a user clicks on the router-link but when I tried using v-on:click.native, the event is not emitting..

I changed it so that the click event is on the `span` tag but that means this only works when a user clicks the text within the `span`.

How should I emit an event from the router-link?

```
  <router-link
    :to="{ name: 'settingsPage' }"
    class="btn btn-md">
    <span @click="closeModal">Go to Settings</span>
  </router-link>


  closeModal(){
    this.$emit('close-modal')
  },
```

Comment: I think it's better to use [beforeRouteLeave hook](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards)

Comment: Could you provide some code we could reproduce? I tried on JsFiddle and everything works fine with `@click.native`: https://jsfiddle.net/wtpuevc6/836/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add event listener to <router-link> component using "v-on:" directive - VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091805/add-event-listener-to-router-link-component-using-v-on-directive-vuejs)

Comment: How about using a normal button/link instead of `router-link`, attaching a `@click` handler, and performing the route action + closing the modal in that handler?

Comment: @dr_barto that's a good idea