# @click not firing on header links for vue.js

Tags: vue.js, click

I want to change a masthead text to the current route name that I am on. It only works on component mount, and does not fire on click. How do I get the changeHeaderTitle to run from the button click created by the router?

```
 <template>
  <div>
    <nav class="navigation--navbar">
      <router-link
        class="navigation--links"
        v-for="routes in links"
        v-bind:key="routes.id"
        @click='changeHeaderTitle'
        :to="`${routes.page}`"
      >{{routes.text}}</router-link>
    </nav>
    <div class="header--headline">
      <h2 class="header--headline-text">{{headerTitle}}</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Navigation',
  data () {
    return {
      headerTitle: 'Boop',
      links: [
        {
          id: 0,
          text: 'Home',
          page: '/Home'
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          text: 'Tutoring',
          page: '/Tutoring'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeHeaderTitle: function () {
      if (this.$route.path === '/') {
        this.headerTitle = 'Home Header Here'
      } else {
        let routeName = this.$route.path.split('/')
        this.headerTitle = routeName[1]
      }
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.changeHeaderTitle()
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Dupl of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091805/add-event-listener-to-router-link-component-using-v-on-directive-vuejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to add `.native` modifier. Do:

```
    <router-link
      class="navigation--links"
      v-for="routes in links"
      v-bind:key="routes.id"
      @click.native='changeHeaderTitle'
      :to="`${routes.page}`"
    >
      {{routes.text}}
    </router-link>
```

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate on this at all?

Comment: Of course! Sorry about the short answer. Basically, `.native` can listen events on the root of the component. For more info, see: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components