# SessionStorage won't assign variable inside click event

Tags: vue.js, local-storage, vuejs3, session-storage

I'm trying to assign a variable to `sessionStorage` like so:

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'admin'}" @click="sessionStorage.auth = false">
```

but it throws this warning:

```
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of native event handler 
  at <RouterLink to= {name: 'admin'} onClick=fn > 
  at <HeaderCms key=1 > 
  at <Cms>
warn @ app.js?id=9ab923fd0732ebefc30fc66fb84cbb22:25050
logError @ app.js?id=9ab923fd0732ebefc30fc66fb84cbb22:25224
handleError @ app.js?id=9ab923fd0732ebefc30fc66fb84cbb22:25216
callWithErrorHandling @ app.js?id=9ab923fd0732ebefc30fc66fb84cbb22:25170
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ app.js?id=9ab923fd0732ebefc30fc66fb84cbb22:25176
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ app.js?id=9ab923fd0732ebefc30fc66fb84cbb22:25186
invoker @ app.js?id=9ab923fd0732ebefc30fc66fb84cbb22:33228
app.js?id=9ab923fd0732ebefc30fc66fb84cbb22:38657
```

followed by this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'auth')
        at onClick._cache.<computed>._cache.<computed> (app.js?id=9ab923fd0732ebefc30fc66fb84cbb22:38657:39)
        at app.js?id=9ab923fd0732ebefc30fc66fb84cbb22:33242:60
        at callWithErrorHandling (app.js?id=9ab923fd0732ebefc30fc66fb84cbb22:25167:22)
        at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (app.js?id=9ab923fd0732ebefc30fc66fb84cbb22:25176:21)
        at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (app.js?id=9ab923fd0732ebefc30fc66fb84cbb22:25186:21)
        at HTMLAnchorElement.invoker (app.js?id=9ab923fd0732ebefc30fc66fb84cbb22:33228:90)
```

How can the property be undefined when I am assigning `false`? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried every variation of this I could think of and the only solution that worked for me was to use **both** a `native` modifier and a method handler:

```js
<template>
  <router-link :to="{ name: 'admin' }" @click.native="onClick" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    onClick() {
      sessionStorage.setItem('auth', false);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

The reason for the `native` modifier is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091805). I'm not entirely sure why the method handler is required, but as you can see in your original error, `sessionStorage` is undefined in your inline handler.

**NOTE** the [sessionStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) uses `setItem` rather than an assignment.

Comment: So, for me it seems to work with just using a function (defined in `vue 3 script setup`) without `.native`. Thank you

Comment: I see. Yeah I'm testing this in Vue 2.

Answer (score 0):

As you can find in the comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091805/add-event-listener-to-router-link-component-using-v-on-directive-vuejs) `"@click.native" is deprecated in Vue.js 3`. So I suggest using a button instead of `router-link` and [navigate programmatically](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html) like the code below:

```html
<script>
import { RouterLink, RouterView, useRouter } from 'vue-router';
export default {
  setup() {
    const router = useRouter()
    function navigate() {
      console.log("navigate");
      sessionStorage.setItem("auth", false);
      router.push("/admin");
    }

    return {
      navigate,
      RouterLink,
      RouterView
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
 
      <nav>
<!--        <RouterLink to="/admin">-->
          <button @click="navigate">Admin</button>
<!--        </RouterLink>-->
      </nav>

  <RouterView />
</template>
```

Notice that I used `useRouter` because `this` is not accessible in [composition API](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api.html). You can then style the button similar to the other links in your app.

From the comments of this answer I found that we can do that in two other ways also:

> using `<a>` tag for better accessibility:

```html
<script>
import { RouterLink, RouterView, useRouter } from 'vue-router';
import {ref} from "vue";
export default {
  setup() {
    const router = useRouter()
    const trueFalse = ref(false)
    function navigate() {
      console.log("navigate");
      sessionStorage.setItem("auth", trueFalse.value);
      router.push("/admin");
    }

    return {
      navigate,
      RouterLink,
      RouterView
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>

      <nav>
        <RouterLink to="/">Home</RouterLink>
        <RouterLink to="/about">About</RouterLink>
        <RouterLink to="/videos">videos</RouterLink>
          <a @click="navigate">Admin</a>
      </nav>

  <RouterView />
</template>
```

> And using `<router-link>`:

```html
<script>
import { RouterLink, RouterView } from 'vue-router';
import {ref} from "vue";
export default {
  setup() {
    const trueFalse = ref(false)
    function navigate() {
      console.log("navigate");
      sessionStorage.setItem("auth", trueFalse.value);
    }

    return {
      navigate,
      RouterLink,
      RouterView
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
 
      <nav>
        <RouterLink to="/">Home</RouterLink>
        <RouterLink to="/about">About</RouterLink>
        <RouterLink to="/videos">videos</RouterLink>
        <RouterLink to="/admin" @click="navigate">
          Admin
        </RouterLink>
      </nav>

  <RouterView />
</template>
```

Comment: It's unfortunate that `click.native` appears to be deprecated in Vue 3. Using a button instead of an anchor could be a reasonable one-off solution. I wouldn't do this all over your app though because it's an accessibility violation.

Comment: Like I wrote below the answer, `.native` is not required for a function with `sessionStorage` to work. So you can keep using `router-link`

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov Thanks for your comment. I updated the answer.